# A code for label values or textbox values will retain empty

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

As the title mentioned, is there a code for label values or textbox values will remain empty if one or more condition has not been met or no choice has been selected?

This is our code and it always gives us 0 values instead of empty.

```
If cboP.SelectedIndex < 1 Or cboP.SelectedIndex > 3 Then
MessageBox.Show("text here", "text here")
txtT.Text = ""
txtL.Text = ""
txtM.Text = ""
txtTl.Text = ""
End If
```

We want the textboxes to remain empty and not 0 values, just empty.

Comment: There's nothing in that code that will cause 0 to be displayed in your TextBoxes.

Comment: It's not causing any specific issues in this case but you should prefer OrElse to Or unless you specifically don't want short-circuiting.

Comment: During design time, a default value to the Text property can be assigned. Make sure it's empty.

Comment: The code you provided is not the cause of this problem. Have you set the default value of TextBox to 0?